# Powershell Outlook e-mail, attachements, subject

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell

So I got a folder with different PDF files ("RG 330526.pdf", "RG 330527.pdf", "RG 330528.pdf") etc.

Now, I want to create a new e-mail, attach the first pdf from a folder (C:\1_PDF) and name the subject just like the pdf file. Save the e-mail in drafts and start over with the next e-mail / next pdf file.

This is what i got so far, i need some help with the loops:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$namespace.Logon($null, $null, $false, $true);
$EmailFrom = ("test@123.com")
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = $EmailTo
$Mail.Subject = $EmailSubject
#$signature = $Mail.HtmlBody
#$Mail.HtmlBody = $EmailHtmlBody + $signature
$account = $outlook.Session.Accounts.Item($EmailFrom)
function Invoke-SetProperty {
    param(
        [__ComObject] $Object,
        [String] $Property,
        $Value
    )
    [Void] $Object.GetType().InvokeMember($Property,"SetProperty",$NULL,$Object,$Value)
}
Invoke-SetProperty -Object $mail -Property "SendUsingAccount" -Value $account

#$Mail.GetInspector.Activate()

$Mail.Save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it done!

This works for me:

```
$WorkDir = "C:\1_PDF"

$RGMailList = Get-ChildItem -Path $WorkDir -Filter *.pdf 

ForEach ($RGMail in $RGMailList)
{
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$namespace.Logon($null, $null, $false, $true);
$EmailFrom = ("test@abc.com")
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "test1@abc.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Subject " + "$RGMail".substring(3)
$account = $outlook.Session.Accounts.Item($EmailFrom)
function Invoke-SetProperty {
    param(
        [__ComObject] $Object,
        [String] $Property,
        $Value        
    )
    [Void] $Object.GetType().InvokeMember($Property,"SetProperty",$NULL,$Object,$Value)
   }
Invoke-SetProperty -Object $mail -Property "SendUsingAccount" -Value $account

$Mail.GetInspector.Activate()
$Mail.Attachments.Add("$WorkDir\$RGMail")
$Mail.Send()}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not showing any code for getting the first file. `Get-ChildItem`, `Select-Object`, etc..
2. You are not saying how you are determining the files, which is
   first. Meaning by name, dateTimeStamps, etc...

What you are after is not new, and there are tons of sample code all over the web and on Youtube.

You don't need outlook necessarily to do this. This is what the...

```
Send-MailMessage
```

...cmdlet can be used for or one of the many modules you can install and use.

```
Find-Module -Name '*mail*'
```

There is nothing wrong with using Outlook, and again, lots of example all over the web. For example:

> https://blogit.create.pt/andresilva/2017/12/07/sending-an-email-with-attachments-using-outlook-and-powershell/

```
# Check to see we have all the arguments
if($args.Count -lt 1)
{
Write-Host "Use: SendMail.ps1 <Path>"
Write-Host
Write-Host " <Path>: Full path for the folder which contains the files"
Write-Host
exit
}

$FullPath=$args[0]

#Get an Outlook application object

$o = New-Object -com Outlook.Application

$mail = $o.CreateItem(0)

#2 = High importance message
$mail.importance = 2

$mail.subject = "This is the subject of the mail"
$mail.body = "This is the body of the email. It has been automatically generated by a script."

#separate multiple recipients with a ";"
$mail.To = <INSERT THE RECIPIENT HERE>
#$mail.CC = <OTHER RECIPIENT 1>;<OTHER RECIPIENT 2>

# Iterate over all files and only add the ones that have an .html extension
$files = Get-ChildItem $FullPath

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {

$outfileName = $files[$i].FullName
$outfileNameExtension = $files[$i].Extension

# if the extension is the one we want, add to attachments
if($outfileNameExtension -eq ".html")
{
$mail.Attachments.Add($outfileName);
}
}

$mail.Send()

# give time to send the email
Start-Sleep 20

# quit Outlook
$o.Quit()

#end the script
exit
```